# Permanently keep an object in memory in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio-server

I understand I can have some objects shared across all user sessions by placing them in `server.R`, but outside of the call to `shinyServer()`. But is there a way to keep those objects stored in memory even if nobody is using the app? It takes a long time for me to load these shared objects from the disk, so I would like to speed things up a little bit for the user by keeping them loaded "permanently".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a file global.R and put the code that loads the data there. However, if the server sleeps or resets information in memory will be lost.

shinyapps.io has a setting "Instance Idle Timeout" you can set to keep an application alive longer. You can also set a value in the config file for shiny server. See link below

http://rstudio.github.io/shiny-server/latest/#application-timeouts

Comment: I could be wrong but has this been changed to app_session_timeout  and now the default is remain open?

Answer (score 2):

One thing you might want to consider is using the global/enclosing environment assignment operator:

```
globalconst <<- x + y
```

This can be used to literally expose variables to the global environment, and persists between Shiny sessions.

Alternatively, you can choose to use the `assign()` function to choose the environment you want to set; there is, I believe, a system variable to handle the environment: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/assign.html